# How to return multi different datatype using qt c++ function?

Tags: c++, qt

I have started qt recently and i was asked i if we can build simple function that return data with different type of int string datatime in one method like login in case i pass the method username and password it i will return all user data where can i call the function in the main form and use the user data there . i have searched and find some example but still  difficult to  a chive i have used this one but it returns only one value no more this is the  code

```
bool database_mysql::test_query(QList<QString>& namesList)
{
    bool result = false;
    namesList.clear();//clear possible old entries

    if(!connect()){
        qDebug() << "Database Not Connected!";
    }else{
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.exec("SELECT * FROM Users");
        while (query.next()){
            QString name = query.value(2).toString();
            namesList.append(name);
         }
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and the code where to pass user name and password to check user 
can any one help.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpair.html

Comment: Return your own data structure aka a struct. This is unrelated to Qt and a fundamental C++ problem. @Jiu pairs shouldn't be used anywhere whether it being QPair or std::pair as it hides the underlying information.

Comment: Use a QVariant, which can hold the most common types: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html if you want to return different things depending on function internals, or a struct/object as already mentioned if you always want to return the same set of things

Comment: QVariant is a useful return type. You can also pass in references as parameters and assign to them in the function rather than return. Aside from that, templates also work.

Comment: thanks but i need an example

Comment: This is more a design question than a code question, you must first think of how and where you will use this data, and then which class should have the data-members, which class will call the DB-query etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your own `class`/`struct` to hold this data. For example, you could create a file `User.h` with the declaration:

```
#pragma once

struct User {
    int       id;
    QString   name;
    QDateTime joined;
    // anything else in your DB
};
```

In your DB module's header (e.g., `database_mysql.h`):

```
#pragma once

struct User; // forward declaration

class database_mysql {
public:
    bool database_mysql::test_query(QList<User>& users);
};
```

Then, in the DB source file (e.g., `database_mysql.cpp`):

```
#include <database_mysql.h>
#include <User.h>

bool database_mysql::test_query(QList<User>& users) {
    ...
}
```

The `test_query` function should then retrieve rows from the DB, instantiate `User` objects, and insert these objects into the `users` list.

Comment: will i add user struct in header file and source file or  only in source file as i have call this method from header file  it will be like this bool test_query(QList<Userdata> &namesList); and what about passing username and password for function to select from database as in c# checkuser(string username , string pass)

Comment: in the login form how will it ?

Comment: I edited my answer to give you an idea of how to structure your source files. As for your other questions, I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: i have the previous steps and then in my main window i have called the function in this way  database_mysql db;
    QList<User> names;
    db.test_query(names);

    foreach(User , names){
      qDebug()<< "Name: " << name;

    }   but i got the error   error: extra qualification 'database_mysql::' on member 'test_query' [-fpermissive] bool database_mysql::test_query(QList<User>& users); ^